# Capitalize my reserved words list in a string

Tags: java, string, java-8

I want to capitalize some reserved words, but I have problems to do it. These are the strings that I'm using:

```
id often refers to identity, identification or backidarenx
the base rate (usd) is a new busda for us [usd for yousdrs]
```

My code below:

```
String value1 = "id often refers to identity, identification or backidarenx";
String value2 = "the base rate (usd) is a new busda for us [usd for yousdrs]";
applyCorrectCase(value1);
applyCorrectCase(value2);

String applyCorrectCase(String value) {
    String[] reservedWords = {"id", "usd"};
    String newValue = value;
    for (String word : reservedWords) {
        if (newValue.contains(word)) {
            newValue = newValue.replaceAll(word, word.toUpperCase());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newValue);
}
```

This is the result:

```
ID often refers to IDentity, IDentification, or backIDarenx
the base rate (USD) is a new bUSDa for us [USD for yoUSDrs]
```

This is that I need:

```
ID often refers to identity, identification or backidarenx
the base rate (USD) is a new busda for us [USD for yousdrs]
```

The problem is that it also capitalizes the letters ID of the word identifier and I do not want that, same for USD and busda.

Comment: Split the string based on word boundary, check whether every word is an exact match for those reserved strings. If they are, capitalize them. Finally, rejoin them together. This is nothing to do with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern to identify the reserved words should look like this:
`"\\b(id|usd)\\b"`, that is, it may be created from the input array of the reserved words where the words are joined inside a group with `"|"`.  To make the matching case insensitive, add the following switch `(?i)`: `"(?i)\\b(id|usd)\\b"`

Next, since Java 9 there is method [`Matcher::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) accepting a conversion function and returning a result string.  There's no need to explicitly split and rejoin the words in the input string.

So, the words may be capitalized as this:

```java
private static final String[] RESERVED_WORDS = {"id", "usd"};


// build the pattern
private static final Pattern RESERVED = Pattern.compile(
    Arrays.stream(RESERVED_WORDS)
          .collect(Collectors.joining("|", "(?i)\\b(", ")\\b"))
    );


static String applyCorrectCase(String value) {
    // replace matched group
    return RESERVED.matcher(value)
                   .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group().toUpperCase());
}
```

Test:

```java
String value1 = "Id often refers to identity, identification or backidarenx";
String value2 = "the base rate (usd) is a new busda for us [usd for yousdrs]";
System.out.println(applyCorrectCase(value1));
System.out.println(applyCorrectCase(value2));
```

Output:

```
ID often refers to identity, identification or backidarenx
the base rate (USD) is a new busda for us [USD for yousdrs]
```

---

For Java 8, plain loop modifying the `value` should be simpler:

```java
static String applyCorrectCase(String value) {
    String[] reservedWords = {"id", "usd"};
    for (String word : reservedWords) {
        value = value.replaceAll("(?i)\\b" + word + "\\b", word.toUpperCase());
    }
    return value;
}
```

As streams are supposed to be stateless and require `value` to be effectively final, this loop cannot be replaced with `Arrays.stream`, a "wrapper" would be needed to update the value in `Stream::forEach` (the simplest wrapper is an array of string initialized with the input `value`):

```java
static String applyCorrectCase(String value) {
    String[] reservedWords = {"id", "usd"};
    String[] result = {value};
    Arrays.stream(reservedWords)
          .forEach(word -> result[0] = result[0].replaceAll("(?i)\\b" + word + "\\b", word.toUpperCase()));
          
    return result[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you adapt this example to Java 8?

Comment: @Despotars, you may check the update

Comment: Hi, I have a new exception, for this string: "Id often refers to identity, identification or backidarenx", can you help me to fix your code to include this exception too?

Comment: @Despotars, I guess it's already resolved

Comment: If the sentence starts like this: 'Id', the function doesn't replace the 'Id' to 'ID', but if it starts like this: 'id' yes, that's my exception that doesn't work with your function. Do you know if its easy to fix it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, sure it can be done by adding `(?i)` key at the beginning of regexp to make case-insensitive matching, you may check the update

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stream`:

```
private static List<String> RESERVED_WORDS = Arrays.asList("id", "usd");

public static String applyCorrectCase(String value) {
    return Arrays.stream(value.split(" "))
            .map(str -> isReserved(str) ? str.toUpperCase() : str)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}

private static boolean isReserved(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("[\\(\\)\\[\\]]"))
            .anyMatch(RESERVED_WORDS::contains);
}
```

Then:

```
String str1 = "id often refers to identity, identification or backidarenx";
String str2 = "the base rate (usd) is a new busda for us [usd for yousdrs]";

System.out.println(applyCorrectCase(str1));
System.out.println(applyCorrectCase(str2));
```

Output:

```
ID often refers to identity, identification or backidarenx
the base rate (USD) is a new busda for us [USD for yousdrs]
```

Comment: I'm using Java 8, so I need to use this: reservedWord=Arrays.asList("id", "USD"); but is not working for me, this is my output: "ID often refers to IDentity, IDentification, or an IDentifier something" & "the base rate (usd) is a new busda for us" Maybe is for the java 8?

Comment: When I edited the answer I did something wrong and modified `reservedWord` from `List.of("id", "usd")` to `List.of("id", "USD")`. I edited the answer to fix the unwanted error and replaced  List.of() with `Arrays.asList()` for java 8 compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

```
String applyCorrectCase(String value) {
    Set<Pattern> reservedWords = new HashSet<>();
    reservedWords.add(Pattern.compile("id"));
    reservedWords.add(Pattern.compile("\\(*usd\\)*"));

    StringJoiner sb = new StringJoiner(" ");

    Arrays.stream(value.split(" ")).forEach(word -> {
        boolean matched = false;
        for (Pattern p : reservedWords) {
            Matcher matcher = p.matcher(word);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                sb.add(word.toUpperCase());
                matched = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!matched) sb.add(word);
    });
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'm using Java 8, this example is not working for me, and the reserved word can not be (usd), becuase maybe the usd in the example is like this: (usd is for you), so the excepcion is different right?